# For a period of time, could life be possible in a black dwarf star?

Tags: science-based, stars

I was thinking about whether it might be possible for life to eventually form in a black dwarf star that has cooled to a point where liquid water forms on its surface. The main questions I have are:

- How long water might be able to last on the surface as the star slowly cools?
- Would the pressure be too high for any water to ever exist?
- Would life be able to function on the residual energy from the centre of the star? Or would the temperature gradient be too small?

Comment: A black dwarf needs somewhere between $10^{15}$ and $10^{25}$ years to cool to 5000K, which is still well above water dissociative temperatures.  I assume you're fine with that?

Comment: Yeah I don't mind how long it takes to get to this point.

Comment: If you roll your mouse over the [tag:science-based] and [tag:science-fiction] tags, you'll learn that they are *mutually exclusive.* Please take a moment to read the wikis for those two tags and then delete one of them.

Answer (score 4):

## No

But for a different reason than Trish's.

A black dwarf, if one were to show up, would be composed largely of [degenerate matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_matter).  You're not going to get water there, because the gravitational pressure would dissociate it, trigger hydrogen fusion (after all, it's a stellar remnant because it's *out of hydrogen*), and add the material to the rest of its mass.

No water, no life as we know it.  This does not discount the possibility of "life as we don't know it", but that is pure, rampant speculation, rather than a definitive answer.

Comment: Would this be the case even on the surface of the star? Presumably if there were a small amount of hydrogen left over when the star finishes its red giant phase, this hydrogen will simply form an atmosphere around the star and not fuse (the pressure at the surface is low). With sufficient oxygen, you could imagine that this might become water?

Comment: @HarryPartridge - no.  A black dwarf is still a stellar mass crushed down to the size of a rocky planet.  A typical white hole (as observed, anyway), has a surface gravity of circa 350000G.

Comment: that may be true, but high gravity != high pressure. I take your point though that due to the high gravity, the pressure would increase very rapidly as you descend into the star, thereby meaning that a hypothetical layer of water probably could not be very thick (if gravity was 350k Gs, then after 1m of water the pressure would be like being under 350km of water on earth, which is 3.5GPa, or just enough for it to become solid VI). Given that this water would come after some amount of atmosphere (i.e. starting pressure != 0), I agree that it seems unlikely that there could be any water.

Comment: However, on a black dwarf arising from a red dwarf (none of which yet exist), the surface gravity would be a lot lower, so it may still be possible to have a thicker layer of warm water on a star.

Comment: Doing some rough calculations based on a lower limit of 0.07 solar masses for a white dwarf, I come up with a theoretical maximum depth of water of 50m. I guess this could be just enough for life, but probably not.